# I want to print all curl scraped value. how do i to that?

Tags: php, curl, xpath

this is my first time in using `Curl` and selecting element within XPath. Attached is my current code.

```
    <?php
//$curl = curl_init('https://silvergoldbull.com/');
$curl = curl_init('https://e-katalog.lkpp.go.id/backend/katalog/list_produk/77/?isSubmitted=1&orderBy=hargaAsc&list=5&manufakturId=all&penyediaId=all&page=1');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}
echo $page; 
curl_close($curl);
$page_doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$page_doc->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

$page_doc_xpath = new DOMXPath($page_doc);
//$result = $page_doc_xpath->evaluate('/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ol/li/a');
$result = $page_doc_xpath->evaluate('string(/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ol/li/a)');
echo "----";
echo $result;

/* $silverprice = $page_doc_xpath->evaluate('string(/html/body/nav/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/span/div/div/strong)');
echo $silverprice; */

/* $buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()') */
/* $regex = '/<div id="case_textlist">(.*?)<\/div>/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else 
    print "Not found";  */
?>
```

by using those code, i am able to retrieve `Computer Supplies` within green bracket at the end of the page. However, how do i retrieve the rest of red brackets ?

update :
i modify `$result` into the following code and still not working. It only return `Networking` instead of all in the brackets

```
$result = $page_doc_xpath->evaluate('string(//div[@class="categoryPath"]//a)');
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use relative XPath `//div[@class="categoryPath"]//a` instead of absolute XPath with hardcoded node indexes

Comment: Hello @Andersson i've changed `$result` into relative XPath like you suggest, but it only return single value `Computer Supplies`. I want to retrieve all in the brackets

Comment: Do not use it as `string(//div[@class="categoryPath"]//a)`, but try as `//div[@class="categoryPath"]//a/text()`

Comment: @Andersson `//div[@class="categoryPath"]//a/text()` only return a blank page. It seems `string(//div[@class="categoryPath"]//a)` is better because it returned a single value.

Comment: Hmm... Then how about `//div[@class="categoryPath"]//string(a)`?

Comment: hi @Andersson it's still returned blank when i use `//div[@class="categoryPath"]//string(a)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use Goutte for scrape the data

```
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$titles = $crawler->filter('.listing--name')->extract('_text');
```

by use class or id can be text of the node...